# Android SDK Samsung Galaxy emulator installation?

Tags: android

as it states in the title I am unable to find Samsung Galaxy option for installation in Android SDK Manager (Revision 20.0.3).

Could anyone help on the matter?

PS: Where ever I looked it is said that there should be third party option or should be under Android 2.3 but it isn't there.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can (and will probably have to) create an emulator image with the specifications of the device you are trying to duplicate. If you are looking for prebuilt ones you'll have to check with the respective manufacturer. If you are expected to see TouchWiz or HTC Sense on the emulator build, you won't as those are proprietary skins.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy supposedly was part of Android SDK, how come it is removed?

Comment: The Android SDK has always provided the open source components, while I do see a Samsung Galaxy Tab entry for 2.2, it would be up to Samsung to provide a pre-built image. Honestly its not that hard to look up the specs for a device and create an emulator image.

Answer (score 0):

But, Android != Android and Samsung use their own modified webkit amongst other things.
Just making a best guess from the hardware specs is going to as effective as using chrome.

Comment: Comments are better off in comments thread of a specific question.